# How to break the line before a date pattern using Shell script?

Tags: java, linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file just like that:

```
13/03/2015 09:21:02 Descrição de log (Sessão terminada);name.lastname -- 127.0.0.1:66666 -> 0.0.0.0 -- 00:01 -- 13/03/2015 09:21:02 Descrição de log (Autenticação realizada com sucesso);name.lastname.....
```

I would like to know how I can break the line every time I have a date. The pattern would be dd/mm/yyyy. So the text would finally be like:

```
13/03/2015 09:21:02 Descrição de log (Sessão terminada);name.lastname -- 127.0.0.1:66666 -> 0.0.0.0 -- 00:01 --             
13/03/2015 09:21:02 Descrição de log (Autenticação realizada com sucesso);name.lastname.....
```

Can someone help me with that? Can be java code, sed, awk, whatever...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's, ([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} ),\n\1,g' filename
```

The `[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}` part of the regex matches a date pattern; the whole regex matches it surrounded by spaces to avoid false positives and because your example data suggests that the input meets this format. `,` is used as a separator instead of `/` in the `s` command because the search regex contains slashes.

Answer (score 2):

With perl:

```
perl -pe 's{(?<=.)(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})}{\n}g'
```

That uses look-arounds to find the place before a date that is not at the start of the line, and puts a newline there.